# mat-select does not display value when doing two way binding in reactive from

Tags: angular, angular-material

i have a reactive from as below :

```
 createInputForm() {
    console.log('creating form');
    this.instituteForm = this.formBuilder.group(
      {
        address: [this.instituteData.address, Validators.required],
        city: [this.instituteData.city, Validators.required],
        pin: [this.instituteData.pin, Validators.required],
        contactNumbers: [this.instituteData.contactNumbers, Validators.required],
        mailId: [this.instituteData.mailId, Validators.required],
        website: [this.instituteData.website, Validators.required],
        allowedGender: [this.instituteData.allowedGender, Validators.required]
      }
    );
  }

ngOnInit(): void {
    this.store.dispatch(new fromInstituteActions.SelectInstitute());
    this.isRequestInProgress$ = this.store.select(fromInstituteSelectors.GetHttpRequestProgress);
    this.store.select(fromInstituteSelectors.GetCurrentInstitute).subscribe(data => {
      this.instituteData = data;
      if (data) {
        this.createInputForm();
      }
      console.log(this.instituteData);
    }
    );
```

and the html temple looks like

```
<mat-form-field>
   <mat-select placeholder="Allowed Gender in institute" formControlName="allowedGender">
       <mat-option *ngFor="let item of genders | enumToArray" [value]="item.key">{{item.value}}
        </mat-option>
   </mat-select>
</mat-form-field> 


@Pipe({ name: 'enumToArray' })
export class EnumToArrayPipe implements PipeTransform {
  transform(value): any {
    const keys = [];
    for (const enumMember in value) {
      if (!isNaN(parseInt(enumMember, 10))) {
        keys.push({ key: enumMember, value: value[enumMember] });
      }
    }
    return keys;
  }
}

export enum AcceptedGender {
  Male,
  Female,
  All
}
```

ideally the mat-option should have a value selected by default which being passed when creating the component. But it's not displaying the value. I am using a pipe to convert the enum to key and value.

Comment: Can you provide a stackblitz? On first look I'd say you have to change [value]="item.key" to [(value)]="item.key"

Comment: @chanakya what you get in `item.key` and  `this.instituteData.allowedGender` ?

Comment: @AnkitPrajapati updated the question with pipe and enum type. Both are integer

Comment: @MikeS. here is the blitz https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-egkrwb

Comment: I've updated my answer, it was actually just a missing .toString() that caused the value to not show :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should be the createInputForm function:

```
 createInputForm() {
    console.log('creating form');
    this.instituteForm = this.formBuilder.group(
      {
        allowedGender: [this.data.allowedGender.toString(), Validators.required]
      }
    );

  }
```

Something to watch out for with your Pipe is also that you dont get 2 as the key, but '2' which caused your version to not show the value

Edit: Stuff